# How to get the week number based on today date

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select the current date based on the weeknumber in the weekstu table.

so lets says we are in week `1` which started `Monday` the `25/11/2013`. I am trying to get that date based on using today date which is the 28/11/2013. Week `2` will be the Monday the `2/12/2013`. The query I have below doesn't return any record. Is this possible to get the beginning of the week based on today date?

```
table:weekstu
weekid
startdate
setid
weeknumber
startdate

Table:week
weekid
setid


    SELECT * from weekstu ws
   JOIN week w ON ws.setid = w.setid AND ws.weekid ON w.weekid
   WHERE ws.weeknumber = `1` AND startdate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Answer (score 2):

You can determine the beginning of the week like:

```
select adddate(curdate(), interval 1 - dayofweek(curdate()) day)
```

Note that a condition like:

```
startdate = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Will only match rows that have the exact current timestamp up to the millisecond.  Unlike `curdate()`, `current_timestamp` contains time information as well as date information.

Answer (score 0):

`DATE_FORMAT(date,format)`

`%b`   Abbreviated month name (Jan..Dec)

`%W`   Weekday name (Sunday..Saturday)

```
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%W')
```

REF: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: ... your example only includes the name of the day, which is unlikely to be unique.  That, and it'll be for _today_ (whatever that happens to be), so it's only going to match 1/7 of the time anyways.  Are you really suggesting he format the date as a string?